# Getting lenght of the list

Tags: python, list

My current program prints all the different sums that are generated with the given integers. Instead of the program printing the content of the list, I would want to print only the lenght of the list.

```
def sums(items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        return items

    else:
        new_list = []
        for i in items:
            new_list.append(i)

        for x in sums(items[1:]):
            new_list.append(x)
            new_list.append(x + items[0])
            new_list = list(set(new_list))

        return new_list

                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sums([1, 2, 3]))                  # should print 6
    print(sums([2, 2, 3]))                  # should print 5
```

Just editing the sums function, instead of `return new_list` I tried to `return len(new_list)` this gives me an error of `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I'm just trying to return the lenght of the list, so I don't really understand the error.

Comment: Your code runs without error for me, if you return the length however, as you have an integer, this will break the recursive function that expects a list as input. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want the sum of unique values, no need for a recursive function: `sum(set(items))`

Comment: Instead of printing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` it should print the lenght of the list, so `6`. Should change the sums function. @mozway

Comment: No, I asked what is the logic of the function, not it's implementation. Why should `sums([2, 2, 3])` return `5`?

Comment: It calculates how many different sums can be generated with the given integers.  list [1,2,3] has 6 possible sums: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6
list [2,2,3] has 5 possible sums: 2, 3, 4, 5 and  7

Answer (score 1):

Use [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(len(sums([1, 2, 3])))            
    print(len(sums([2, 2, 3])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the function, you are getting the error because it is recursive (returning value is important), change this section instead

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(len(sums([1, 2, 3])))              
    print(len(sums([2, 2, 3])))
```